# free instances of db2 on IBM cloud unavailable after reactivate

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I have two free instances of db2 on IBM Cloud.

Both expired (went inactive), and i re-activate them today.
But none of the are accessible now. I can't access them from a local client, and the Console can not Open.

I tried creating a new free instance, and it works fine.
How can i recover access to the free instances after they were re-activated ?

Thanks

Comment: how mudh time elapsed between the expiry-date and reactivation date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Db2 on Cloud Lite is being upgraded to new infrastructure this week. Please find your hostname on this schedule: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-faq-lite-plan-migration. Your migrated instance on the new infrastructure will be available 24 hours after the migration date.

Comment: thanks. it worked. I can access now one of the dbs (using new hots, port, and password).
However, for the second one, i can't get access by client. It says user is revoked (but i can access it via Cloud GUI console)